# How to extract viewstate and eventvalidation using regular expression parsing partial renders with JMeter ASP.net

Tags: jmeter-4.0

In my case, I am able to extract `viewstate` and `eventvalidation` from response, when the response is like:

`<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="UGflz/O67VPwTmNdi......"`

by giving expression as:

```
name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.+?)"
```

but what is the expression i need to use, when the response is like:

```
 |hiddenfield|__viewstate|koflrijcjafaygr......|
```

How can I extract this type of response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use "\" to escape | as

for example to extract viewstate value from

> |hiddenfield|__viewstate|koflrijcjafaygr......|

You can use this regular expression **__viewstate\|(.+?)\|**

You can follow [this blogs](https://www.redline13.com/blog/category/jmeter/)  for such information

Comment: Thankyou Rohit Thankyou very much.
You really saved me

Comment: @shiva  if it helped you can accept the answer,see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Rohit I was looking for it. Thank YOU

Answer (score 0):

I have applied below and make it work

expression:  VIEWSTATE|(.+?)|

Template:$1$

Match No: 1[image]